# Resize item's height of a listview populated from CustomAdapter (ArrayAdapter<DrawerItem>)

Tags: android, listview, height, navigation-drawer

I am stuck on this for several days now.

In my main activity, i have a listview contained in a drawerlayout(android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout).

I created a CustomAdapter class with custom items, and i inflate different layout depending the items i add to the arraylist through the adapter.

**My problem is the following :**

-The height of every rows is automatically set to the height of the most important item's height  that my list contain.

**This is what i would like :**

-I want the height of each row to correctly wrap the content.....Meaning not leave some empty space between the bottom of the layout and the divider.

**This is what i tried with no success:**

-Set the layout_height of the parent layout to "wrap_content" in my custom_drawer_item.xml.

-Tried the android:minHeight in my custom_drawer_item..xml.

-In my code, i tried to use setLayoutParams(). Here is the relevant part :

```
 dataList = new ArrayList<>();
 mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
 mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);  

    dataList.add(new DrawerItem(true)); // adding a spinner to the list
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Pictures")); // adding a header to the list
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Options & Links")); // adding a header to the list
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Settings", R.drawable.ic_action_settings)); // adding a Link/Button to the list
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Help", R.drawable.ic_action_help)); // adding a Link/Button to the list
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("About", R.drawable.ic_action_about)); // adding a Link/Button to the list

    CustomDrawerAdapter adapter = new CustomDrawerAdapter(this, this, R.layout.custom_drawer_item, dataList);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
    View item0 = getViewByPosition(0,mDrawerList);
    item0.getLayoutParams().height = 110;
    View item2 = getViewByPosition(2,mDrawerList);
    item2.getLayoutParams().height = 25;
    View item3 = getViewByPosition(3,mDrawerList);
    item3.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,25));
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

 ...


     public View getViewByPosition(int pos, ListView listView) {                         
    final int firstListItemPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    final int lastListItemPosition = firstListItemPosition + listView.getChildCount() - 1;

    if (pos < firstListItemPosition || pos > lastListItemPosition ) {
        return listView.getAdapter().getView(pos, null, listView);
    } else {
        final int childIndex = pos - firstListItemPosition;
        return listView.getChildAt(childIndex);
    }
```

**---------**

**In advance, thanks for all those who could help :) !**

**---------**

**Relevant part of activiy_main.xml :**

```
...
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:layout_gravity="start|left"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:divider="@color/Bluexxxx"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
...
```

**custom_drawer_item.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="10dp"
android:background="@drawable/list_selector" >

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/profileLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/counter_bg_profile" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/picture"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/profile_picture1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/edit_profile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/picture"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/picture"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/age"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/user_name"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/city"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/age"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/spinnersLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:minHeight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/spinnerLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:minHeight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/current_m_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="false"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/current_m_text"
            android:textColor="@color/Bluexxx"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/Spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/current_m_text"
            android:prompt="@string/prompt_c"
            android:hint="@string/hint_s"
            android:spinnerMode="dialog"
            android:popupBackground="@color/background_material_light"
            android:dropDownVerticalOffset="0dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/itemLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="50dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/drawer_icon"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/drawer_itemName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Constructor of "CustomDrawerAdapter" class :**

```
public class CustomDrawerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DrawerItem> {

protected Context context;
protected Activity activity;
protected List<DrawerItem> drawerItemList;
protected int layoutResID;
protected String TAG = "CustomDrawerAdapter";
protected PopupWindow pWindow;

public CustomDrawerAdapter(Activity activity, Context context, int layoutResourceID, List<DrawerItem> listItems) {
    super(context, layoutResourceID, listItems);
    this.activity = activity;
    this.context = context;
    this.drawerItemList = listItems;
    this.layoutResID = layoutResourceID;
}
```

Comment: Nobody is able to help on this matter ? I am still stuck on this...

Answer (score 0):

I just put your custom_drawer_item.xml into layout editor, and I think what's causing your heartburn is this:

```
    .
    .
    .
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/Spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        .
        .
        .
```

With a height of `match_parent`, your `Spinner` is trying to be as big as it can.

You've also got some other problems, like a stray namespace declaration at line 9 from a cut & paste operation.

Comment: Unfortunately, even if it will works, it requires a lot of modifications in my code, and not fast ones.....Is there any way just to modify individually each the height of the rows once a listview has been populated ?

Comment: Just did...it doesn't address my issue. Yeah my spinner, is as big as it can...it is the way i want. I want to reduce the height of his parent...and his parent is a row of my listview . The problem, if you want me to rephrase, is "How to make a listview not setting the same height for each of his row ?" ....In my case, all my row are set to the height of the bigger one...